# Wrapping a callback function in a single threaded fashion

Tags: java, multithreading

In my program, I am essentially trying to connect to a publisher and get data.  The basic functionality is there in these steps

1. I make the connection to the publisher with username and password etc
2. I make the request for data.  Method exits
3. The publisher's API gives me a callback to a method `onDataUpdate(Object theUpdate)`

From there, I can print the data, or write it to a database or anything I need to do.  That all works.

My problem is, I would now like to wrap the functionality in such a way that a calling program can say request the data and receive it as soon as I have it.  Meaning, I want my exposed method to look like

```
public Object getData() {
    subscribeForData();
    // somehow wait
    return theUpdate;    
}
```

How can I make this happen?  Is there some way I can use threads to wait/notify when I've received the update?  I'm a newb to stackoverflow and also multithreaded programming, so any help and sample code would be much appreciated!!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would prefer to use [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), where i'll initialize my `lathch` with count 1 as soon i subscribe for publisher i will call `await(`) on `latch` and when i get the callback i'll `countdown` the `latch`.

Comment: From javadoc of CountDownLatch: `A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.` Bull's eye!

Comment: Do you have any examples of this?  I can't seem to get it to work.  I created a new CountDownLatch in my calling class and passed it to the class which will actually receive the update.  So they both have references to the same latch.  In my onDataUpdate method I call countDown on the latch, but it doesn't seem to notify the other class which is just waiting indefinitely.  Thoughts?

Comment: I got it working - I couldn't make it work with a reference to the same latch in another class, but I created a call in the class where it was created which did the countdown for me and that worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a SynchronousQueue. Create it in getData, call put() in the callback method, then call take() in the original thread at the end of getData().

Answer (score 0):

Check out CompletionService, especially [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).  There is a nice example of a web page loader/renderer in the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain about your question but I'll give it a shot - hope it helps :)

You could use a blockingqueue in java for this purpose (producer consumer message) - if you write to the queue when the callback gets invoked - from another thread, you could read from the queue.  Blocking queues are thread safe (but may not fit your requirements).

You could also look into readwrite locks if you only have one thread writing to a collection and perhaps multiple readers (or even just on reader).

You could also look into the observer pattern - for reference: http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html

If neither of those work, one could look into using a queue/topic from an in-VM messaging server such as ZeroMQ/ActiveMQ or perhaps something like Redis/HazelCast.

Hope it helps and good luck

Answer (score 0):

Converting a asynchronous call to a synchronous one is an interesting exercise, I use it often in interviews (and the reverse, wrapping a synchronous call in asynchronous).

So there is a `requestData` method that is going to return immediately and it (or something else) will later call `onDataUpdate` in *a different thread*. You want to create a new method, say `requestDataSynchronous` that does not require the caller to use a callback but instead *blocks* till data is available and returns it to the caller.

So what you need for `requestDataSynchronous` to do is:

1. call `requestData`
2. wait till `onDataUpdate` is called (in a different thread)
3. get the data `onDataUpdate` received
4. return it to the caller

Of the above, #2 and #3 have to be done by some mode of inter-thread-communication. You can use `wait`/`notifiy` but it might be much simpler to use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). `onDataUpdate` writes to it once data is available, and `requestDataSynchronous` reads from it, blocking on the read until `onDataUpdate` writes into it.

Using `ExecutorService` might make this even easier, but it will be useful to know what's going on.

Comment: Thank you!  I used the CountDownLatch for now because it seemed simpler.  Is there any benefit to using a BlockingQueue I might not be thinking of?  You sound like a tough interviewer :-)